# Estimating Redshift Table Size

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to create an estimate for how much space a table in Redshift is going to use, however, the only resources I found were in calculating the minimum table size:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-cluster-storage-space/

The purpose of this estimate is that I need to calculate how much space a table with the following dimensions is going to occupy without running out of space on Redshift (I.e. it will define how many nodes we end up using)

Rows : ~500 Billion (The exact number of rows is known) 
Columns: 15 (The data types are known)

Any help in estimating this size would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The article you reference is excellent. What do you find inadequate in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article you reference ([Why does a table in my Amazon Redshift cluster consume more disk storage space than expected?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-cluster-storage-space/)) does an excellent job of explaining how storage is consumed.

The main difficulty in predicting storage is predicting the **efficiency of compression**. Depending upon your data, Amazon Redshift will select an appropriate [Compression Encoding](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Compression_encodings.html) that will reduce the storage space required by your data.

Compression also greatly improves the speed of Amazon Redshift queries by using **Zone Maps**, which identify the minimum and maximum value stored in each 1MB block. Highly compressed data will be stored on fewer blocks, thereby requiring less blocks to be read from disk during query execution.

The best way to estimate your storage space would be to **load a subset of the data** (eg 1 billion rows), allow Redshift to automatically select the compression types and then **extrapolate** to your full data size.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was initially going down this path, but wanted to see if there was a faster way of calculating this.